# Passing variable to onclick function in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a variable in ajax and i want to send it onclick event. here..

```
function childID(Obj){
        var replayId = Obj.id;
        // var replayId = '"#'+replayId+'"';
        // console.log(replayId); 
     }
```

And I want to save it onlick event..

```
$('#allcomments').on("click", replayId, function(){  
     console.log('something action...'); 
 });
```

here allcomments is the parent id and replaId is not exit on loding page..

Comment: Where is your `AJAX` function? Define the url you want to send your variable to, define the `type:` (i.e. `POST`), define the variable in your `data:{ }` set and add an onclick event to your `AJAX`, or encapsulate it into some function that you define and call that function `onclick`. Perhaps consider elaborating your question so that it becomes 100% clear. Perhaps explain in detail what your desired result is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Clousures to maintain state

```js
function childID(Obj){
  var replayId = Obj.id;
  // var replayId = '"#'+replayId+'"';
  // console.log(replayId); 
  function outer (id) {
     // id will remain in scope of this function and will be accessable to inner callback
     return function inner () {
      console.log('something action...', id);
     }
  }
  $('#allcomments').on("click", outer(replayId));
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the variable `replayId` as a local variable, to the `function childID(Obj)`.

```js
function childID(Obj) {
  var replayId = Obj.attr('id');
  return replayId;
}

$('input[type=button]').on("click", function() {
  var theID = childID($(this));
  alert(theID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="button" id="drink" value="Drink Me"></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="eat" value="Eat Me"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### Edit

Without more of your code, it's difficult to create a robust answer. I also don't fully understand your plight. The purpose of AJAX is to not rely on multiple pages for the functionality. Everything - save for things like API calls - should be done on the page itself.

Here's another snippet I've built, based on a commenting system. It's using two functions - which could be turned into one - on the page with the comments, which returns values for use in AJAX.

```js
function findCommentID (comment) {
 return comment.parents('li').attr('id');
}

$('#allcomments li li').on('click',function(){
 var commentID = findCommentID($(this))
 var commentAct = $(this).attr('class')
 
 /* Do your AJAX calls here */
 alert(commentID + " " + commentAct)
});
```

```css
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  }

p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
  }
  
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
  
ul ul {
  text-align: right;
  }
  
li li {
  display: inline;
  padding: .5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  }

li li:hover {
  background-color: #FDD;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="allcomments">
 <li id="comment1">
  <h2>Comment 1</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porta, quam eget hendrerit molestie, felis mi placerat tellus, sed imperdiet augue ipsum non quam. Praesent et nisl eu dolor sagittis fringilla. Quisque mi dolor, porttitor quis nunc sed, pulvinar pellentesque ex. Donec cursus volutpat orci quis dapibus. Maecenas id erat id mi blandit viverra pharetra non leo. Cras ut eros sit amet dolor feugiat molestie et a massa. Mauris velit enim, interdum ut diam at, condimentum bibendum enim. Curabitur dignissim consectetur ligula, in scelerisque orci placerat et. Vivamus tristique sem quis massa sodales elementum. Etiam non aliquet augue, a tincidunt ligula. In eget urna sit amet leo feugiat interdum.</p>
  <nav><ul><li class="reply">REPLY</li><li class="report">REPORT</li></ul></nav>
 </li>
 <li id="comment2">
  <h2>Comment 2</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porta, quam eget hendrerit molestie, felis mi placerat tellus, sed imperdiet augue ipsum non quam. Praesent et nisl eu dolor sagittis fringilla. Quisque mi dolor, porttitor quis nunc sed, pulvinar pellentesque ex. Donec cursus volutpat orci quis dapibus. Maecenas id erat id mi blandit viverra pharetra non leo. Cras ut eros sit amet dolor feugiat molestie et a massa. Mauris velit enim, interdum ut diam at, condimentum bibendum enim. Curabitur dignissim consectetur ligula, in scelerisque orci placerat et. Vivamus tristique sem quis massa sodales elementum. Etiam non aliquet augue, a tincidunt ligula. In eget urna sit amet leo feugiat interdum.</p>
  <nav><ul><li class="reply">REPLY</li><li class="report">REPORT</li></ul></nav>
 </li>
 <li id="comment3">
  <h2>Comment 3</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse porta, quam eget hendrerit molestie, felis mi placerat tellus, sed imperdiet augue ipsum non quam. Praesent et nisl eu dolor sagittis fringilla. Quisque mi dolor, porttitor quis nunc sed, pulvinar pellentesque ex. Donec cursus volutpat orci quis dapibus. Maecenas id erat id mi blandit viverra pharetra non leo. Cras ut eros sit amet dolor feugiat molestie et a massa. Mauris velit enim, interdum ut diam at, condimentum bibendum enim. Curabitur dignissim consectetur ligula, in scelerisque orci placerat et. Vivamus tristique sem quis massa sodales elementum. Etiam non aliquet augue, a tincidunt ligula. In eget urna sit amet leo feugiat interdum.</p>
  <nav><ul><li class="reply">REPLY</li><li class="report">REPORT</li></ul></nav>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but the loding page only have <div id = 'allcomments'> <div> and replayId exit on another page. here all result retrieve by ajax. My replayId's value is the id to click to some action like '#replay'. please help me out..